# How to do i print some numbers using .sample() from the random built in module in python

Tags: python

I working on a problem where I'm supposed to generate ten random but unique numbers that range from 1 to 15 inclusive. The thing is, I'm supposed to write everything in one line and to also get this output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15]
```

Below I have some code I wrote but, it's not getting the output I want. What am I doing wrong and can I perhaps see a solution with a break so I know how to do this going down the road?

```
import random

print(sorted(random.sample(range(1,16),15)))
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

The output I want is:

```
[2,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,15]
```

How do I get this in one line of code?

Comment: If you want 10 numbers, why are you asking for 15?

Comment: your chance to get your desired out is :  1 in 3003 :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as typo/can't be reproduced, since the issue is that asking for 15 numbers produces 15 numbers, and not 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm supposed to write everything in one line and to also get this output:
>
> ```
> [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15]
> ```

```
>>> sorted(__import__('random').Random(4225).sample(range(1, 16), 10))
[2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> help(random.sample)
```

> sample(population, **k**): method of random.Random instance
>
> Chooses **k** unique random elements from a population sequence or set.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate ten numbers in range 1-15, change

```
print(sorted(random.sample(range(1,16),15)))
```

to

```
print(sorted(random.sample(range(1,16),10)))
```

Comment: `range` is half-open. `range(1, 15)` is missing 15.

Comment: Oh whoops didn't notice that. Thanks!

Comment: This is not working the way i want to. i want the output to display [2,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,15] . I get ten numbers from this but not in the sequence that i want. how can i get the output i just described in one line of code.

Comment: If you want specifically [2,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,15] , then just do `print("[2,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,15] ")`.

Comment: or `print(sorted(random.sample([2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15],10)))`

Comment: Sorry guys guess i got it right. all i had to do was print out random numbers the way i did a and sort them out. it was some home work. i thought my instructor wanted me to print that nice little list i had presented you all here, Thanks everyone for all the help. your answer were all right.

Answer (score 0):

```
# From the documentation :
# random.sample(population, k)

import random

population = range(16)
how_may_sample = 10

random.sample(population, how_many_sample)

# Now in one line
random.sample(range(16), 10)
```